# How can I speed up my python query (large sets of JSON with multiple API calls)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, optimization

I need to run a script that will log into multiple instances of a product and pull all of the data into a centralized list. There are 4 regions and each region may have 1,000 devices.

Each region is setup identical. If I want to crawl the list of devices, I first make an API call to /api/device which only returns a URI and description.

```
"result_set":[
{
"URI":"/api/device/1",
"description":"ardmore"
},
{
"URI":"/api/device/10",
"description":"oban"
}
]
```

I then have to make an API call to /api/device/ which has a whole lot more data, including more pointers (URIs)

```
{
"name":"ardmore",
"ip":"1.2.3.4",
"hostname":null,
"snmp_cred_id":"/api/credential/snmp/79",
"snmp_w_cred_id":null,
"class_type":"/api/device_class/7A126AD829FF5CD0B2525A658D4EEB17",
"organization":"/api/organization/518"
}
```

So now I finally have the device 'name' and 'ip', but if I want the "Class Type" (contains two values, 'Vendor' and 'Model) and "Organization" it's two more API calls.

It seems to me there has to be a way to just 'suck in' all of these tables into some list, and then just query things as I go. I'm still quite new to Python so I'm sure it's a dumb idea and there's some much better way I've never considered.

Modified script is below, this is enough to give you the jist of things. There are even more API calls etc, but this should be enough to show the overall flow.

```
def list_assets(Region):
    url = 'https://db01.' +str(Region)+ '.myhost.net/api/device?limit=3000&filter.0.state.eq=Active'
    response = requests.get(url,data=data,headers=headers,verify=False)
    data = response.json()
    return(data)

def getDetails(Region,URI):
    url = 'https://db01.' +str(Region)+ '.myhost.net/' +str(URI)
    response = requests.get(url,data=data,headers=headers,verify=False)
    data = response.json()
    return(data)

def getClass(Region,URI):
    url = 'https://db01.' +str(Region)+ '.myhost.net/' +str(URI)
    response = requests.get(url,data=data,headers=headers,verify=False)
    data = response.json()
    vendor = data['class']
    model = data['description']
    return(vendor,model)

def getCompany(Region,URI):
    url = 'https://db01.' +str(Region)+ '.myhost.net/' +str(URI)
    response = requests.get(url,data=data,headers=headers,verify=False)
    data = response.json()
    Company = data['company']
    return(Company)
    
    
regions = {"APAC","EU","US","AU"}

for region in regions:
    devices = list_assets(region)
    for device in devices['result_set']:
        URI = device['URI']
        details = getDetails(region,URI)
        hostName = details['name']
        IP = details['ip']
        ClassURI = details['class_type']
        Vendor,Model = getClass(region,ClassURI)
        OrgURI = details['organization']
        Company = getCompany(region,OrgURI)
        csvOut = [hostName,IP,Vendor,Model,region,Company]
        writer.writerow(csvOut)
```

Comment: How fast is it going currently ? And how fast should it be going ?

Comment: It's painfully slow right now, each device probably takes 5 seconds. I was mostly curious if there's any novice/amateur changes I could make to speed things up. Something like parallel processes is way over my head right now, but maybe I made some simple mistake in my logic, or there's some JSON function I don't know about that can speed this up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) :

```py
import time
from math import log10, ceil

import tqdm  # used only for displaying throughput


ACTUAL_TIME_PER_DEVICE = 5 / 4  # 5 seconds, split between 4 API calls
DEMO_TIME_SPEEDUP = 1000  # to make things faster for demo purposes
DEVICES_PER_REGION = 1000


def fake_list_assets(region):
    # fetching is slow ...
    time.sleep(ACTUAL_TIME_PER_DEVICE / DEMO_TIME_SPEEDUP)
    # returning 1000 fake device's ids
    return {
        "result_set": [
            {"URI": f"{region!s}_device_{str(i).zfill(ceil(log10(DEVICES_PER_REGION - 1)))}"}
            for i in range(DEVICES_PER_REGION)
        ]
    }


def fake_get_details(region, uri):
    time.sleep(ACTUAL_TIME_PER_DEVICE / DEMO_TIME_SPEEDUP)

    return {
        "name": f"fake name for {region=!r} {uri=!r}",
        "ip": f"fake ip for {region=!r} {uri=!r}",
        "class_type": f"fake class_type for {region=!r} {uri=!r}",
        "organization": f"fake organization for {region=!r} {uri=!r}",
    }


def fake_get_class(region, uri):
    time.sleep(ACTUAL_TIME_PER_DEVICE / DEMO_TIME_SPEEDUP)
    return f"fake vendor for {region=!r} {uri=!r}",\
           f"fake model for {region=!r} {uri=!r}"


def fake_get_company(region, uri):
    time.sleep(ACTUAL_TIME_PER_DEVICE / DEMO_TIME_SPEEDUP)
    return f"fake company for {region=!r} {uri=!r}"


counter = tqdm.tqdm(unit="devices")


regions = ["APAC", "EU", "US", "AU"]
for region in regions:
    devices = fake_list_assets(region)
    for device in devices['result_set']:
        URI = device['URI']
        details = fake_get_details(region, URI)
        hostName = details['name']
        IP = details['ip']
        ClassURI = details['class_type']
        Vendor, Model = fake_get_class(region, ClassURI)
        OrgURI = details['organization']
        Company = fake_get_company(region, OrgURI)
        # print([hostName, IP, Vendor, Model, region, Company])
        counter.update(1)  # add 1 to the counter
```

which gives me :

```
4000devices [00:16, 245.69devices/s]
```

Around 16 seconds but with a `1000` speedup factor, it means it would have actually taken around 4 hours and 30 minutes.

The problem is that you run your code serially, with much of the time waiting for the server to answer. This is a situation called `I/O bound` because your code runs as fast as the I/O it receives, in this case the time to receive each request's answer.

Ideally, we would like to be `CPU-bound`, which means that the computer is going as fast as it can, but it just can not go as fast as the server is answering the requests.

To do that, you need to make your requests **parallel**, either using [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) or [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). It happens to be just the situation that [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) is meant to solve.
I use [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) because it makes things simpler to write :

```py
import concurrent.futures


counter = tqdm.tqdm(unit="devices")


regions = ["APAC", "EU", "US", "AU"]


def fetch_all_info_for_one_device(region, device_uri):
    details = fake_get_details(region, device_uri)
    ClassURI = details['class_type']
    OrgURI = details['organization']
    Vendor, Model = fake_get_class(region, ClassURI)
    Company = fake_get_company(region, OrgURI)
    hostName = details['name']
    IP = details['ip']
    return hostName, IP, Vendor, Model, region, Company


NUMBER_OF_WORKERS = 40  # you can change this value

# fetch the few regions to prepare all the data
all_devices_uris_to_fetch_by_region = {}
for region in regions:
    region_devices = fake_list_assets(region)
    all_devices_uris_to_fetch_by_region[region] = tuple(device["URI"] for device in region_devices["result_set"])

# create an executor which will run all the tasks submitted with `map` to its workers
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUMBER_OF_WORKERS) as executor:
    all_params = tuple(
        (region, device_uri)
        for region, devices_uris in all_devices_uris_to_fetch_by_region.items()
        for device_uri in devices_uris
    )
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(
        executor.submit(fetch_all_info_for_one_device, *params)
        for params in all_params
    ):
        device_result = future.result()
        # print(device_result)
        counter.update(1)
```

```
4000devices [00:00, 9099.61devices/s]
```

It went too fast ! Reducing the demo time speedup : `DEMO_TIME_SPEEDUP = 10` gives instead

```
4000devices [00:38, 105.04devices/s]
```

At 10x speedup only, it means the real code would run in about 6 minutes. Assuming that the server can handle the load.

If you don't want to go parallel, maybe the server provides other APIs ? Instead of fetching the data uri by uri, maybe it is possible to give a list of uris and and receive a list of results ? It would have a lot of impact too I think.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate this. I was afraid that running things in parallel was the only real answer and was just way too intimidated to try. I did look at async yesterday, but it was way over my head. I don't understand this, but you've given me enough to 'google' that I'll be able to figure it out and make sense  soon enough. Sadly, I don't think there is any way to browse the entire API listing without going piece by piece. 

Seriously, thank you so much for taking the time to write that all out, I really appreciate it.

Comment: To be precise, you need to make things **concurrent** (several tasks can be in progress, but may be running one at a time), not necessarily **parallel** (actually running at the same time). For this reason, you can use at least **threading** or **cooperative multitasking** (i.e. async on one thread), or else **multiprocessing**. I recommend you [this RealPython article](https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/) if you want a good intro to the subject. And write your concurrent code iteratively, with lots of `print`s, to keep an understanding of what is going on.

Comment: Thanks. I'm working on trying to test this out now, but it seems the last bit of your code (the `with concurrent.futures` bit) isn't formatted properly? There's some crazy indenting going on, and two of the `for` statements only have a ")" at the end. I'm struggling to figure out which for loops should be nested where.

Comment: @ChadDa3mon I just copy-pasted in PyCharm the code from the first part (until `regions = ["APAC", "EU", "US", "AU"]`) then all the second part, ran and it worked. So I do not reproduce your formatting issue. Anyway I just edited my answer to reformat a bit this part, making the nesting clearer. I hope it helps. I admit that I did not write the code in the simpler way. If this second version is still too convulted for you, please notify me and I will take some time to explain this part better.

Comment: Thanks, I got things working. My version of the script ran for over 3 hours before eventually finding an error with one of the devices and breaking. 

Your version runs in 4.5 minutes.....That's insane!

Comment: @ChadDa3mon Your initial code was wasting ~99% of its time waiting to receive answers, so making the tasks concurrent yields a ~100x speedup. Your problem was very prone to benefit from this approach. Also, you can adjust the `NUMBER_OF_WORKERS`, which could make it even faster. [This website](https://superfastpython.com/threadpoolexecutor-in-python/#How_Many_Threads_Should_You_Use) recommends to set it to the number of tasks, but no more than 1000 (the threads created by the executor are **native** threads, not **green** threads, so you risk exhausting your operating system capabilities).